# Reading PDF per Line

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How can I read a PDF file `line by line` using iText5 for .NET?
I have search through the internet but I only found reading PDF file per page content.

Please see below code.

```
public string ReadPdfFile(object Filename)
{

    string strText = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)Filename);

        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

            String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

            s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
            strText = strText + s;

        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return strText;
}
```

Comment: I think this is difficult, because theres no clear newline mark in pdf

Comment: Is there anyway to convert the text content of pdf into image file? is it possible??

Comment: Try a search for "PDF 2 IMAGE", lots of components. But why you only convert text to image? What about pictures? And.. if you already have text, you can create image yourself.

Comment: I have an application displaying a pdf content (scanned image). but somehow, it throws an error upon loading pdf file with vector content. That's why i need to convert it first into image content before loading it on my application.

Comment: iText is rather document generation oriented. It's manipulation capabilities seems to be limited at page level. You'd better look for other solution.

Comment: @menjaraz is correct. iText and iTextSharp can ***read*** and ***write*** PDFs but not ***render*** them which is what is required to create images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, use the`LocationTextExtractionStrategy` instead of the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` it will add new line characters to the text returned. Then you can use strText.Split('\n') to split your text into a `string[]` and consume it on a per line basis.

Answer (score 3):

You can find [here](http://www.colorpilot.com/pdf2text.html) the **PDF2Text Pilot** licensed under BSD Open-Sourse software.

Despite that it's written in c++, it may serve as an an inspiring good start toward solving your problem.

I'm not proficient in C# but I think there might be some hope on the interoperability side ?

Answer (score 3):

I worked for a eBook reading company and PDFs, we spent *a lot* of time and effort trying to get the reading order of text, since the reader could read to you ... bouncing dot ... PDFs do not have to have line by line sequence. Books also have lots of elements that are *not* in reading order including page number, references, captions, examples, multi-column, etc.. It's a hard problem. PDF is basically a print format at its heart.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a eBook reader for PDF, either just show as what PDF is, same look as other pdf ready does. Or read the text out and reformat yourself.

I prefer the second method, just format the text whatever nice since if I use the ebook reader, I just care the content and never care about what it should look like