# Parsing PDF by line

Tags: parsing, powershell, line, itext

I've been able to parse a PDF by page multiple ways, the latest being this (not my code):

```
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader  -ArgumentList "oldy.pdf"

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
    $strategy = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'            
    $currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy);
    [string[]]$Text += [system.text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::Convert( [system.text.encoding]::default, [system.text.encoding]::UTF8, [system.text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($currentText)));
}
```

I found a post here that suggested using LocationTextExtractionStrategy instead and splitting each line out by '\n'
However, I will admit that the .NET code here is confusing me and i'm not sure how to modify it to parse by string.

Can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question "Parsing PDF by line" because the concept of lines doesn't exist in a PDF. Maybe that's your problem: maybe you see lines because you're looking at the page with human eyes, whereas a machine can only read the PDF syntax, a syntax that is based on an imaging model that can produce lines without using the concept of lines.

Comment: He's talking about this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8451913/231316

Comment: that's correct, i bet it isn't difficult to edit the .NET code to create an array of lines instead of pages,,,but I can't seem to figure it out just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Only a first experiment, but it works as expected:

```
# Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Add-Type -Path itextsharp.dll

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList MyFile.pdf

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
  # extract a page and split it into lines
  $text = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader,$page).Split([char]0x000A)

  Write-Host "Page $($page) contains $($text.Length) lines. This is line 5:"
  Write-Host $text[4]

  #foreach ($line in $text)
  #{
  #  any tasks
  #}
}

$reader.Close()
```